# Find partial key and their value from Map<String, String> in java

Tags: java

I've this map key value pair as :

```
{$skip=28, $landingPageURL=https://www.example.com, $gtmCount=gtmMPCL, $url=mpclProd, $trackingJson=mpclNonAmpTracking.json, $portalCD=portal_CD_MPCL}
```

and I need to findout the key as  $landingPageURL?utm_medium=lp_automation from the above map. So, my final output should be for `**$landingPageURL?utm_medium=lp_automation** as https://www.example.com?utm_medium=lp_automation` (because $landingPageURL is replaced with above map).

How do I achieve this with condition something like

> ```
> if(map.partialcontainskey(keyname) so, as example, it should conditionally check if
> $landingPageURL.partialcontainskey($landingPageURL?utm_medium=lp_automation).
> ```

how do i achieve this. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input is following

```
String input = landingPageURL?utm_medium=lp_automation;
```

You can split the input string and get the required key as follows:

```
String[] urlComponents = input.split("?");
String key = urlComponents[0];
String queryString = urlComponents[1];
```

And finally you can generate your output as follows:

```
String output = map.get(key)+"?"+queryString;
```